# Convert visual studio 2008 project to 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am now working with a big project which is developed in `visual studio 2008`, `SCSF` and `LINQ query`. Now i want to upgrade my project to 2010. Is there any tool so that i can convert all of these to new technology?

Answer (score 3):

It automatically upgrades your solution when you open it in Visual Studio 2010.

[**How to: Upgrade Projects Created in Earlier Versions of Visual Studio**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185327.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> 1.In Visual Studio, on the File menu, click Open and then click Project/Solution, Web Site, or File, depending on the kind of project
>   you are upgrading.
>
> 2.In the Open Project dialog box, select a project file, and then click Open.
>
> If Visual Studio detects that the project or file was created in an
>   earlier version of Visual Studio, the Visual Studio Conversion Wizard
>   opens.
>
> 3.Complete the Visual Studio Conversion Wizard.

This will work.